# Inplace upgrad 2008R2 SQL Server to 2014 for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server-2014

I currently have 2 Windows 2012 servers to support a 2013 SharePoint environment.  One server has 2008R2 SQL on it, and the other server has SharePoint 2013.  Both of these servers are virtual machines and due to time constraints I would like to do an "in-place" upgrade with no changes.  Is this possible and what should I look out for?  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with in-place SQL Server upgrades; they've generally been quick (<20 minutes) and without issues. You should make sure your SharePoint 2013 farm is up to date before you patch, or at least patched above SP1 + May 2014 CU.

What I'd recommend if you absolutely have to do an in-place upgrade of SQL:

1. Turn off your SharePoint server.
2. Backup all of your databases.
3. Perform the upgrade. Verify with SSMS that your databases are online/not showing any errors.
4. Turn on your SharePoint server.